# macOS Focus: How to allow notifications from commandline apps

Tags: terminal, command-line, notifications, focus

I use a small utility to notify me when a commandline application finishes (in this case https://github.com/variadico/noti, but there are various solutions for this). I also use the new Focus modes. But how do I make sure these notifications are allowed?

They show up in the notification center, but are suppressed. I can't find the app, nor the "Terminal" application to add to the list of allowed apps:

[image: screenshot of adding Focus Allowed apps]

Any idea how to allow this so I don't have to turn this off on my Mac?

Comment: Have you found any workaround for that?

Comment: @Hauleth unfortunately not.